# Only the left half of the button is clickable in IE

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer, button

I have a code for a button in my HTML, and the button is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, however in Internet Explorer (10), only half the button is clickable!

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" data-ng-if="Ctrl.diaplay" data-ng-click="Ctrl.reload('custom')" class="submit__button">
```

I don't know how to explain what is happening better, but in IE, if you hover near the left edge of the button, it is clickable, however when you hover near the right edge, the button is not clickable.

Comment: You probably have another element overlapping it. Can you inspect the right half in IE dev tools?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what is was. There was a blank <div> which was overlapping. Is there a way to make the <div> which has the submit button active without changing the overlapping <div>?

Comment: I have this same issue except in Google Chrome, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127346/button-only-partially-clickable-error